# How Do I Create Copy Of Array in New Thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, copy

I use this method to create the copy of array but I doubt , I opened thread and sent array with new Thread , If I dont create copy of this array in new Thread, array may change and this effects my program mechanism badly.

```
   degersakla = new Integer[10000][1][boyut];
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

   new GunlukKontrol(update, data, limit, degersakla, sincetime, untiltime);

                                    }
                                });
    t1.start();
                                try {

                                    Thread.sleep(400000); // Waiting For new Thread's Copy Operation
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(UpdateDeneme.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
  // new Thread
    public GunlukKontrol(Object[][][] update, String[][] data, Object[] limit, Integer[][][] degersakla, String sincetime, String untiltime) {

    this.degersakla = new Integer[degersakla.length][1][boyut]; // copy method of array
    for (int i = 0; i < degersakla.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < boyut; k++) {
                this.degersakla[i][j][k] = degersakla[i][j][k];
            }

        }
    }
```

Is this right method ?

Comment: an array of arrays of arrays? are u sure?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the array in the first thread after you have *started* the second thread, then you have an issue.

The issue must be solved by passing a *copy of the array* to the second thread. If you let the second thread copy the array, you have not avoided the data race on the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.degersakla = Arrays.copyOf(degersakla, degersakla.length);
```

This will perform a deep-copy and it is very fast.

Both your code and this are **not** thread-safe. You need to implement a locking mechanism to ensure that:

```
final Object arrayLock = new Object();
//...
synchronized(arrayLock) {
  myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length);
}
```

But you need to call synchronized **every time** you access the array:

```
synchronized(arrayLock) {
  myArray[5] = 12;
}
```

If that is too complicated, you can use a [concurrent class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), but then you need to change a lot of your code.